# Extract Key from URL with Preg_Match in PHP

Tags: php, string, url, preg-match

I haves this URL
https://test.com/file/5gdxyYpb#_FWRc4T12baPrppZIwVQ5i18Sq16f7TXU82LJwY_BjE

I need to create with preg_mach this condition:

`$match[0]=5gdxyYpb#_FWRc4T12baPrppZIwVQ5i18Sq16f7TXU82LJwY_BjE`

`$match[1]=5gdxyYpb`

`$match[2]=_FWRc4T12baPrppZIwVQ5i18Sq16f7TXU82LJwY_BjE`

I try difference pattern the mos closed was this one. `e\/(.*?)\#(.*)`.

Please any recommendation. (If necessary in Preg_Match).

Thank you,

Comment: I suggest you add any code you have tried to accomplish what you are trying to achieve into your question.

Comment: Explode("#", $url) ?

Comment: In preg_match, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use 2 capturing groups and make use of `\K` to not match the first part of the url to get the desired matches.

```
https?://.*/\K([^#\s]+)#(\S+)
```

- `https?://` Match the protocol with optional s, then `://`
- `.*/` Match until the last occurrence of `/`
- `\K` Forget what is matched until here
- `([^#\s]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ occurrences of any char except a `#` or whitespace char
- `#` Match the `#`
- `(\S+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ occurrences of a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vAYyqZ/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/IBBXV)

```
$url = "https://test.com/file/5gdxyYpb#_FWRc4T12baPrppZIwVQ5i18Sq16f7TXU82LJwY_BjE";
$pattern = "~https?://.*/\K([^#]+)#(.*)~";
$res = preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5gdxyYpb#_FWRc4T12baPrppZIwVQ5i18Sq16f7TXU82LJwY_BjE
    [1] => 5gdxyYpb
    [2] => _FWRc4T12baPrppZIwVQ5i18Sq16f7TXU82LJwY_BjE
)
```

Comment: Yeeesss, you are a GENIUS. The key was /K command. Realy THX. Just curiosity what are you use for get this kind of patten.

Comment: @Torronf You are welcome. I use the regex101 tester. This site can also be helpful https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#other